# content attribute of img elements

Tags: google-chrome, css, image, web-standards

While inspecting the Chrome Dev tools, I noticed the following CSS fragment:

```
img {
    content: url(image-src.png);
}
```

which works perfectly in Chrome (see Screenshot below).

[image: Chrome Dev Tools]

This allows me to define the src attribute of an <img> tag via CSS. Doesn't work in Firefox. Until now I thought that is not possible to directly modify the src attribute via css and I have not found anyone talking about this. **So, is this just a proprietary addition in Chrome or is Chrome implementing a W3C draft or something comparable I am not aware of?**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[The `content` property as defined in CSS 2.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#propdef-content) applies to `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements only. By CSS rules, you can specify any property for any element, but specifications have limitations on what properties “apply to” (i.e., have effect on) various elements.

The [CSS3 Generated and Replaced Content Module](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-content/), a Working Draft, describes the [`content` property](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-content/#content) as applying to all elements. It has an example of replacing the content of an `h1` element by an image, and surely the same could be done to an `img` element.

But it’s just a Working Draft. The usual resources on CSS implementation status, [QuirksMode.org CSS info](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html) and [Caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/), do not indicate the situation; they only describe the support to `content` for `:before` and `:after` (which is rather universal except IE 7 and earlier.

Comment: Not only is it just a WD, but it seems to be abandoned. I have no clue where these implementations are going or whether they're ever going to implement this module completely.

Comment: @BoltClock, the WD hasn’t been worked on since 2003, but in the W3C overview document http://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/current-work.en.html it’s in the “Rewriting” section, not “Abandoned”. There’s an Editor’s Draft dated 17 April, 2012, though I don’t know how its content relates to the 2003 draft. I would expect support to `content` for normal elements become more common; in addition to Chrome, Opera and Safari already support it.

Answer (score 0):

**Now you can do that:** http://chabada.esy.es/tests/0004.html

```
<style>
  .redcross {
    background: transparent url('redcross.png') no-repeat;
    display: block;
    width:  24px;
    height: 24px;
    }
</style>

<img class="redcross">
```

Comment: But you need to know the pixel dimensions of the image, otherwise it will be cropped.