# replace <br> with characters/string using css?

Tags: css, replace, character

i'm looking for a solution to replace a line break `<br>`
with a character, let's say a comma.

i'm having a website that displays credits to images.
in landscape mode credits are displayed like this:

title 
artist 
year

in portrait mode it should be displayed like this:

title, artist, year

so far i found this solution, works in safari, safari for ios and chrome (haven't tested chrome on android but i guess it should work too):

first set an empty content to remove the line break

```
br {content: '';}
```

then set the string you want the line break to be replaced with

```
br:after {content: ', ';)
```

if you need the line break to work normally again put

```
br {content:none;}
```

works great actually but is it the right way to do this?
how would you replace a line break with a character in css?
i'm looking for a solution in which the end user of the cms doesn't have to add too much html code when entering the credits.

Comment: This shouldn't work as `content` should only work with the `:before` and `:after` pseudo-classes

Comment: Hi and welcome on SO. I don't see any question here so I guess you want to answer one of your own question? This is perfectly accepted but you must pretend to ask a question (How would somebody...?) and then answer it below.

Comment: @IanClark First http://stackoverflow.com/a/11175158/137626 and it at least has some effect somewhere (Chrome?) on replaced elements (input? img?) that triggers a "oh now I've content and I'll behave differently"... Sorry for being so vague ;)

Comment: But a `br` is an empty/void element, so it can't contain any content.

Comment: @IanClark Found the link [CSS generated content on replaced elements](http://www.red-team-design.com/css-generated-content-replaced-elements) while kalley had already posted it :) Google is my extension memory...

Comment: thanks for your answers and sorry for the mess!
i edited the question.
still using this "feature" as i haven't found a better solution yet.

Answer (score 2):

Self-closing tags (eg. `<br>`, `<img>`, `<input>`, etc) can't have generated content. These are replaced elements.

For more information on replaced elements, see this article:http://www.red-team-design.com/css-generated-content-replaced-elements

Comment: Good link, and I think it confirms that this behaviour should be treated more as a bug than a solution to this issue.

Answer (score 1):

```css
/* cross browser inline-block */
p br {
  display: -moz-inline-stack;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  zoom: 1;
  *display: inline;
}

/* replace <br> with comma */

p br {
  content: '';
  width: 9px;
  height: 18px;
}

p br:before {
  content: ', '
}
```

```html
<p>some<br />text with &lt;br&gt;</p>
```

works in mobile Chrome 40.0.2214.89, Chrome 40.0.2214.95, Opera 12.16, Safari 7.0.4

not work in Firefox 35.0.1 and Internet Explorer 11