# Links with image-backgrounds in Android browser

Tags: html, css, android-browser

I have small problem with some  tags which has images in background,  and text inside a tags is indented in css, but in Android browser i see part of that string, which is used in html. This word is covering background image (area of a tag). Code and screenshot from mobile looks like this:

image: http://s29.postimg.org/tctfbp9jb/sa_sc.jpg

```
<li class="item185">
<a class="soc-link" href="#">rss/sapa</a>
</li>
<li class="item186">
<a class="soc-link" href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/..">facebook/sapa</a>
</li>
<li class="item187">
<a class="soc-link" href="#">youtube/sapa</a>
</li>
```

css:

```
li {
    display: inline-block;
}
a.soc-link {
    background-position: -4px 0;
    background: url("../images/sapa-bg.png") no-repeat;
    display: block;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0 0 0 1em;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-indent: 10000px;
    width: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Posting the code is easy.  Just copy it from your source.  When you paste it here in your question, highlight it and click on the button that looks like squiggly brackets.

Comment: thanks, this is my second post here...

Answer (score 0):

Use css:

```
content:'';
```

for those elements.
You can use this css:

```
color: rgba(255,255,255,0);
```

Just to be sure.

Comment: Big thanks. [This topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11173991/content-attribute-of-img-elements) covers something, that I didn't know, that You can use content property for elements, not just for pseudo-elements. **But this didn't work in this case.** Only transparent color saved it. You just forget to put **rgba** before brackets.

Comment: oh, sorry about rgba, my bad. Edited my answer for future visitors with the same problem.