# HTML5/CSS3: Hover Image Replacement

Tags: html, css, hover

I've read multiple solutions here on Stack Overflow, but I still haven't found my solution. I've tried adding image goes here and manipulating #one:hover with CSS, but nothing happened.  Using image goes here and manipulating #one:hover with CSS I get limited results, but they're all wrong.  The original image never gets replaced, and a very thin line of the replacement image appears underneath my original image.  Here 's my code:

HTML5:

```
<nav>
<p/><p/>
<a id="one" href="form.html"><img src="nav.email.gif" alt="E-Mail Form" width="256px" height="100px"/></a>
</nav>
```

CSS3:

```
#one:hover 
{
background-image: url('nav.email.ani.gif'); 
width:256px; 
height:100px;
}
```

Using "background" instead of "background-image" gives me nothing, and using a div tag gives me nothing. I tried absolute placement of the replacement image, but again all I got was a thin line instead of a full size image (even when using width and height). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is suggest is to use `background-image` to `img` element like:

```css
#imgOne:hover {
  background-image: url('http://placehold.it/200x100');
  width: 256px;
  height: 100px;
}
#imgOne {
  background-image: url('http://placehold.it/400x200');
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <p/>
  <p/>
  <a id="one" href="form.html">
    <img id="imgOne" src="" alt="E-Mail Form" width="256px" height="100px" />
  </a>

</nav>
```

Comment: You're sugesting to use an empty Image element and atach a background image to that? Why don't just do it with the a tag instead?

Comment: Because OP use `img` element. Dind't want to change html structure.

Comment: If that's the case, fine. But I don't see that requirement in the question.

Comment: I'm sorry, it's 4 am and I haven't had a chance to read through all of the answers yet, due to an illness in the family. So far,  I've just read this first one. And it's **brilliant**. There's only one problem: There's a white border around my image on my otherwise black web page. I tried adding color:#000; border-color:#000; and border-width:0px; to my imgOne{} code, but nothing works. Suggestions for getting rid of this 1 pixel white border are welcomed!!

Comment: If this border comes from the image can't do much. Otherwise you  can remove the border. Do you have any link of your site or a link to the image you refer to?

Comment: Use a <div> instead of an <img> element (effectively creating an element with a background image is all you are doing anyway, the <img> tag really isn't being used). The blank src="" is causing the border to display (in Chrome, mostly).

Answer (score 1):

Here is another alternative.

```
<a id="one" href="form.html>
     <img title="email" src="nav.email.gif" onmouseover="this.src='nav.email.ani.gif'" onmouseout="this.src='nav.email.gif'" />
</a>
```

Comment: Why use Javascript here? There ain't no need to do that.

Comment: Just an alternative that I thought could be useful.

Comment: My problem with it, is that it will only work, if Javascript is enabled. I know it's enabled in 99.9% of all cases, but still you shouldn't use Javascript for styling, that can easily be done in CSS.

Comment: Appreciate solutions like this - not all of us are concerned with disabled JS or browser differences.

Answer (score 0):

Using Pure [css content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content) is fast and easy

```css
#one:hover img{ content:url("http://placehold.it/400x200") }
```

```html
<nav>
  <p/><p/>
  <a id="one" href="form.html">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x100" alt="E-Mail Form" width="256px" height="100px"/>
  </a>
</nav>
```

or You can Use @Alex Char answer or use this alternative solution.

```css
#one img:nth-child(2) 
{
    display: none
}

#one:hover img:nth-child(1) 
{
    display: none
}
#one:hover img:nth-child(2) 
{
    display: block
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <p/><p/>
  <a id="one" href="form.html">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x100" alt="E-Mail Form" width="256px" height="100px" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/400x200" alt="E-Mail Form" width="256px" height="100px"/>
  </a>
</nav>
```

Comment: Why not just using the a tag with background images? I agree that the advantage with your solution would be preloading, but we could fix this by using a sprite.

Comment: @wawa i don't want to use the anchor tag beacause of the `href` and Search Engine Optimization.

Comment: How would it impact the href? For SEO reasons you could but some text in the a tag and hide it with css (text-indent: -9999px;)

Comment: @wawa soory i got you first question wrong i made some update

Comment: @wawa: I'd steer clear of using 'hacks' like `text-indent: -9999px;`, especially when you want to update your code in the future. Keep your css clean, simple, and reusable.

Comment: Is content save to use on an image? See this discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11173991/content-attribute-of-img-elements

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have, is that the backgroung image is assigned to the a tag, but then have a image overlaying it.

I'd try this:

```
#one {
    display: inline-block; /* keep it as inline nide but make it aware of width and height */
    width: 256px;
    height: 100px;
    background-image: url('nav.email.gif');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    text-indent: -9999px; /* to hide the SEO text */
}

#one:hover {
    background-image: url('nav.email.ani.gif')
}
```

Important: remove the img tag and put some text for SEO reasons in the a tag, if you like:

```
<a href="form.html" id="one">Some text for SEO reasons like Contact-Formular foo bar baz</a>
```

*SEO text is optional.

Answer (score 0):

## Option 1: Using Css 'Hover'

Rather than using an img tag, why don't you use a 'normal' div element? That way, you can do something like the snippet below, which sets the background for both the 'normal' and 'hovered' version within the css itself?

```css
div {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: url(http://placekitten.com/g/200/200);
}
div:hover {
  background: url(http://placekitten.com/g/200/500);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

## Option 2: Replace Using Javascript/JQuery

You could use javascript at this point to replace the image's src, but I (personally) feel this would be a slower/less efficient approach than using css, Although, it would go along the lines of:

```
$("#myImageID").hover(function(){
    $(this)...
});
```

Comment: Are you sugesting to put the div inside tha a tag? Otherwise you'd loose the abillity to click. If you do so, be aware, that you shouldn't put a block element inside a inline element. Also I don't see the point in using Javascript here (specially jQuery, since it's an additional resource that has to be loaded)

Comment: @wawa: In terms of you being 'against' the jquery, (1) Did you read my comments on it, and (2) it could also be done with 'vanillaJS'. In terms of your *"block element inside a inline element"*, there are many ways around this issue *ever* arising.