# How to detect browser support for "picture" element

Tags: javascript, html

As part of updating my website to be more mobile friendly I need to serve up different images based on screen/browser size.
I've come across using the "picture" element which works great when it's supported.  The problem at this time is that it's not supported everywhere.
I'd like to detect if the "picture" element is supported by the browser so I can fall-back to a different method.

How can I detect if the "picture" element is supported by the browser?

Since this is the only type of check I currently need, I'd like to avoid pulling in a library (ex. Modernizr) if possible.

Answer (score 13):

Finding out if `picture` is supported is actually quite simple:

```
var pic = !!window.HTMLPictureElement;
console.log("picture supported: " + pic);
```

This will print `false` if your browser needs a workaround or `true` if it supports `picture`. Clearly it doesn't necessarily mean that support for `picture` is also complete and great (and as of early 2016 it's probably still work in progress in many browsers).

Regardless of the `picture` element having a fallback built-in, I believe there are legitimate reasons for wanting to know whether a browser supports the `picture` element or not.

For example you might want to provide your own workaround instead of using something massive like the [picturefill.js](https://scottjehl.github.io/picturefill/) polyfill.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to detect browsers at all.

The `<picture>` specification requires that the last child element of the `<picture>` is an `<img>`.

If `<picture>` isn't supported than the `<img>` will be rendered as normal. The `<img>` is your fall-back.

Comment: The <img> is my fall back for my typical screen size (desktop in my case).  But I need to fall back on a method to provide a different image for the non-default image size (ie. mobile).  In my case it will fall back to Javascript.  I just need the logic to identify if such a fallback is needed, which is the case when the <picture> element is not supported.

Comment: The question asked specifically about detecting picture element support, so I'd say this is an incorrect answer.

Comment: @duncanwilcox — The question clearly states that the goal is to provide a fallback. It also makes a false assumption that detecting picture support was required for that. This answer addresses the actual problem.

Comment: @Quentin - As explained above, the actual problem is presenting a suitable size image based on device screen size (in this case, mobile devices).  So I need the fall back to support various resolutions.  The <img> element does not support this natively to my knowledge.  So your proposed answer (while appreciated) to use the default behavior of falling back to <img> does not address the actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I've come up w/ so far.

**NOTE**:  I've only been able to test this in Chrome on Galaxy S4 & S5, WebView on Galaxy S4, and Chrome on iPhone 4.  My code will skip this code on larger screens so I don't need to test there (it'll never execute this code).  So between the limited testing plus the "hacky" approach on this (just smells bad) plus my limited knowledge of the feasibility/reliability of this approach, I'm not confident this is even a feasible approach (let alone a good one).

```
var mypic = document.createElement('picture');
// Will be '[object HTMLPictureElement]' when supported; '[object HTMLUnknownElement]' otherwise
var strObj = '' + mypic;
if(strObj.indexOf("HTMLPictureElement") != -1)
{
    // Picture element supported
}
else
{
    // Picture element not supported
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Quentin is right; JS is not needed. However, if you need to change the image URL based off a media query, you can use CSS. You may want to consider using this instead of the `<picture>` tag altogether.

```
@media (min-device-width: 600px) {
    .myimage {
        content: url(myimage.jpeg);
    }
}
```

The breaking point (600px in this example) is up to you.

Comment: This is interesting and looks promising based on the content here.  But from a few google searches [1](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_gen_content.asp), [2](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/content/), it seems the 'content' CSS property is for use w/ the :before and :after pseudo-elements.  [This SO page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11173991/content-attribute-of-img-elements) suggests it's not in the formal spec and has varying support.  More research for me...