# Override image source with style declaration containing base64 image data?

Tags: html, css, image

Let's say I have an image in a document that point to a standard default no image. Is it possible to specify a class that I can use to overwrite that value with a base64 value?

HTML:

```
<img src="loading_icon.png" class="image1"/>
<img src="loading_icon.png" class="image2"/>
```

CSS:

```
<style>

    .image1 {
        src: text/base64: ABCD...;
    }

    .image2 {
        src: text/base64: ABCD...;
    }

</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `content` but [it won't work in all the browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11175158/8620333)

```css
.image1 {
  content:url(https://i.picsum.photos/id/10/200/200.jpg)
}

.image2 {
  content:url(https://i.picsum.photos/id/17/200/200.jpg)
}
```

```html
<img src="loading_icon.png" class="image1">
<img src="loading_icon.png" class="image2">
```