# Is there a way to specify an image file in css so that depending on the CSS file, the image is different?

Tags: html, css

For an html header, a div box containing elements including a logo, would it be possible to put the logo as well as the colors in the css file? For example:

```
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="myurl.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<div class="header">
  <div class="header-left>
    <img id="logo"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

In the stylesheet, I would like to say

```
#logo {
    src: mylogo.jpg;
}
```

so that the look and feel is all within the stylesheet. Then to select a different skin, the only thing needed is to switch the stylesheet.

Comment: duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/q/61419282/8620333

Comment: Note: the `<link>` and `<img>` tags do not use and do not need a closing slash and never have in HTML.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I define colors as variables in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1875852/how-can-i-define-colors-as-variables-in-css)